# using fourier series to find the sum of series

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

I have a question about this.
Using only the fact that 
$$ 1 + \frac{1}{3^2} + {1 \over 5^2} + .... = {\pi^2 \over 8} ,$$

can we show 
$$ 1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + {1 \over 3^2} + {1 \over 4^2} + .... = { \pi^2 \over 6}. $$
I know that the second sum has to equal that, but I don't know how to show it using just that fact?
thank you!

Comment: $$\frac{\pi^2}{8}+\frac14 S = S$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah! Think about the latter sum as:

$$(1+1/3^2+1/5^2\cdots)+(1/2^2+1/4^2+1/6^2)=k$$

$\therefore (\pi^2/8)+(1/4)(1+1/4+1/9\cdots)=k$
... and you notice something astonishing!

$$\pi^2/8+k/4=k$$ which Ron Gordon essentially said.
Take it from here to solve $k$

Comment: thank you for the help, now that I see writing out the sum using the formula making it very clear

Comment: @Khoata Upvote? :)

Comment: yeah i try to vote for your answer but it says I didn't have enough reputation or something like that.

Comment: @Khoata try the check mark thing